# SetACLs on Parse Server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm using Parse Server on AWS and its been going well. However I am unable to assign ACL as I did in the parse.com cloud code.

I have read [The Compatibility Notes](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-Server/wiki/Compatibility-with-Hosted-Parse#Cloud-Code), [Docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide) and [Git Read me](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) however there is very little mention of ACL.

The following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662409/parse-server-cloud-code-setting-acl) has been tried, however it is not working for me.

My old code was like this :

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Favourites", function(request) {
    var user = request.user;
    var newACL = new Parse.ACL(Parse.User.current())
    newACL.setReadAccess(user, true);
    newACL.setWriteAccess(user, true);
    request.object.setACL(newACL);
    request.object.save();
});
```

Obviously `Parse.User.current()` cannot be used which has brought me to this:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Favourites", function(request, res) {

    var acl = new Parse.ACL();
    acl.setReadAccess(request.object.id, true);
    acl.setWriteAccess(request.object.id, true);
    request.object.setACL(acl);
    res.success();

});
```

However, this is not working for me.

I have also tried setting the ACL at the same time as saving using the following, however it still doesn't work for me.

```
var favourites = new Favourites();

var acl = new Parse.ACL();
acl.setReadAccess('request.object.id', true);
acl.setWriteAccess('request.object.id', true);
favourites.setACL(acl);

favourites.save({
    user: request.user,
    favourites: request.params.favourites
}, {
    success: function(favourites) {
        console.log('Great!')
    },
    error: function(favourites, error) {
        console.log('The save failed');
    }
});
```

EDIT

I have just tried doing things using the Javascript Docs:

```
  var favourites = new Favourites();

    var acl = new Parse.ACL(request.user);
    acl.setReadAccess(request.user, true);
    acl.setWriteAccess(request.user, true);
    acl.setPublicWriteAccess(false);
    acl.setPublicReadAccess(false);
    favourites.setACL(acl);
    favourites.set("favourites", request.params.favourites);
    favourites.set("userId", request.user.id);
    favourites.set("user", request.user);
    favourites.save({}, { useMasterKey: true });
```

Still doesn't work!

It seems there is a serious lack of node.js cloud code examples in the Docs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can't Parse.User.current() be used?  If I'm setting an afterSave() on an object created by a mobile client (using say the iOS sdk) how does the sdk pass the user object?

Comment: `Parse.User.current()` cannot be used on the nodeJS version of Parse Server see here: http://blog.parse.com/learn/using-node-js-with-parse/

Comment: Thanks - btw, the answer you linked to in your post worked for me on Heroku.  I wonder why it didn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need to do. I have add deny access fir the public, since it isn't totally clear what you want.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Favourites", function(request) {

    var newACL = new Parse.ACL();

    // Are you sure you don't need to disable public access?
    newACL.setPublicReadAccess(false);
    newACL.setPublicWriteAccess(false);

    // Give access to user
    newACL.setReadAccess(request.user, true);
    newACL.setWriteAccess(request.user, true);

    // Assign ACL to object
    request.object.setACL(newACL);

    // Use master key
    request.object.save(null, {useMasterKey: true});
});
```